# Making uploded file get random name not working

Tags: php, string, random

So i want my uploded file to get a random number at the end of the file name ,but the rand() function is not working

```
$post_image = rand($_FILES['image']['name'],1,100);
$image_tmp = rand($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],1,100);
move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"../img/$post_image");
$insert_query = "insert into posts
(post_title,post_date,post_author,post_image,post_keywords,post_content) values 
('$post_title','$post_date','$post_author','$post_image','$post_keywords','$post_content')";
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: rand works fine, you just didn't bother to read the manual on how to use it properly. it accepts either no arguments, or 2 integers. Not one string and two integers

Comment: How can i make it working ,i am kind new to php do i need another variable?

Comment: It feels like you are asking the wrong question. What are you trying to do / prevent?

Comment: I am trying to add some random number when my image is uploaded and moved to another folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name can be something like `myimage.jpg`

You need to add a random number before the extension, using something like

```
$parts = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);
$filename = $parts['filename'];
$extension = $parts['extension'];

$post_image = $filename . rand(1, 100) . '.' . $extension;

// image_tmp does not need a random number added.
$image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
```